# Jenkins checkout scm step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm new to Jenkins and I'm trying to understand the following step in Jenkins pipeline line by line:

```
checkout scm
                dir("some_directory") {
                    checkout(
                        changelog: false,
                        poll: false,
                        scm: [
                            $class                           : 'GitSCM',
                            branches                         : [[name: SOME_BRANCH_NAME]],
                            doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                            extensions                       : [[$class: 'CloneOption', depth: 0, honorRefspec: true, reference: '', shallow: false]],
                            submoduleCfg                     : [],
                            userRemoteConfigs                : [[url: SOME_URL]]
                        ]
                    )
                    sh 'pwd; ls'
                }
```

From the research I've done I understood that

```
checkout scm dir("some_directory")
```

'dir' creates a folder in workspace if it doesn't exist, and git project gets checked out into this directory

```
checkout(
       changelog:false,
       poll:false,
       scm: [...]
)
```

this block of code specifies git parameters of the git project that is being checked out into the directory specified above.

This is so far what I understood, can someone please lt me know if my understanding is correct? And possibly add more details to it.

Also, I am confused with the current code syntax. Would it make any difference if I rewrite the top few lines as:

```
checkout scm dir("some_directory")(
            changelog: false,
            poll: false,
            etc.
)
```

instead of using 'checkout' two times.

Comment: Have you seen https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-scm-step/ and https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/?

Comment: @MattSchuchard yep, I've seen those, thanks!

Comment: Then I believe the part of the question the documentation does not directly address is the differences between the two `checkout`. The first is the simplified step method which assumes most of the inputs. The second is the full class that allows more robust parameter definition. In this pipeline, the first is likely retrieving the base code for the application, and the second is likely retrieving some other code.